# Using The Fourier transform To Prove An Identity Of The Hessian

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-analysis

By using the Fourier transform prove that if $u \in C_0^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ [twice differentiable and vanishes at $\infty$] then

\begin{equation} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \det H(u) \,dx\,dy = 0 \end{equation}  where $H$ is the Hessian.

Attempt: We have $H(u) = u_{xx}u_{yy} -  u_{xy}^2$ then

\begin{equation} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \det H(u) \,dx\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u_{xx}u_{yy} - u_{xy}^2 \end{equation} Then by Plancherel's theorem we have

\begin{equation} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}  u_{xy}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\widehat{u_{xy}}|^2 \,d\xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \xi_1^2\xi_2^2|\hat{u}|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \xi_1^2\hat{u}\xi_2^2\overline{\hat{u}} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \widehat{u_{xx}}\overline{\widehat{u_{yy}}} \end{equation} However I am unsure of how to use this identity to show that
\begin{equation} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \widehat{u_{xx}}\widehat{u_{yy}} \,d\xi = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} u_{xx}u_{yy} \,dx\,dy \end{equation}

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The book also claims it holds for arbitrary dimensions in the sense that if $u \in C_0^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then
\begin{equation} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \det\text{H}(u)  = 0 \end{equation}

Comment: You say "The book also claims that it holds for arbitrary dimensions."  Can you please edit your question to include a complete citation to this text?

Comment: sure, I just did.

Comment: By "complete reference," I mean that you should give the title of the text, the name of the author, and, perhaps, a link to the book at some reputable website (Google books, the publisher's website, etc).

Comment: Check here Eq. 2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem

Comment: @XanderHenderson https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-96 (Lecture Notes on Elliptic and Parabolic Equations in Sobolev Space by Krylov. Page 3 exercise 2)

Comment: @Thomas Ah, thank you so much! I forgot about that identity! That resolves the question!